# I want to draw a pie chart of maximums

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, pie-chart

I have a dataframe like this:

```
dog_stage   favorite_count
8   doggo   32467
11  puppo   38818
13  puppo   15359
25  pupper  21524
34  doggo   20771
```

I want to draw a pie chart of the most favorite dog_stages

Answer (score 0):

Group them together and draw a pie chart with the pandas plotting function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
dog_stage favorite_count
8 doggo 32467
11 puppo 38818
13 puppo 15359
25 pupper 21524
34 doggo 20771
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df.groupby('dog_stage')\['favorite_count'\].sum().plot(kind='pie', title='favorite count', ylabel='',autopct="%1.1f%%")
```

[image]